# Visa renewal to the USA

Tags: visas, b1-b2-visas, visa-extensions

I have a B1/B2 US visa valid from 18 Nov'14 - 16 Nov'19, however, have not visited the US during this period and do not foresee visiting by the 16th November this year.  There were several changes in my circumstances (family, finances, etc.) over the past few years that did not enable me to visit. I wish to extend my visa for future visits, hopefully, next summer. Will this be ok? Kindly advise. Thank you.